# Fortran runtime error: Cannot open file (No such file or directory)

Tags: fortran

Disclaimer: I'm using a program written in FORTRAN and I'm having trouble using it. I'm not proficient in FORTRAN at all. I apologise in advanced if this is a dummy question.

I'm getting the following error:

```
At line 1494 of file phot_star_fit18.f90 (unit = 45)
    Fortran runtime error: Cannot open file '/Users/.../SSPFITTING/GASFIT/ssp/ssplist.d': No such file or directory

Error termination. Backtrace:
#0  0x10a0a9729
#1  0x10a0aa3f5
#2  0x10a0aab59
#3  0x10a16f70a
#4  0x10a16f950
#5  0x10a09815c
#6  0x10a09ee5e
```

Line 1494 is:

```
open(unit=45,file=splist,status='old',action='read')
```

In the `/Users/.../SSPFITTING/GASFIT/ssp/` directory I have the following files relating to `ssplist`. something:

```
ssplist.dat2
ssplist.dat04
ssplist.dat5
ssplist.dat08
```

Could anyone shed some light on why this is failing and why the code is expecting a `ssplist.d` file?

Comment: `...` is strange. Probably `..`?

Comment: well its looking for `ssplist.d` not `.dat`. or any other thing

Comment: Please show us the declaration and assignment/initialization for `splist` as it does seem not to be what you expect.

Comment: @francescalus I'll certainly add this to my question.

Comment: My suspicion is that the variable `splist` is too short to hold the whole file name.

Comment: @chw21 Could you maybe add for me a possible solution, I think it could be this too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not enough data in the question to ascertain whether this really is the issue, but I have a strong suspicion:

It tries to open a file called `/Users/.../SSPFITTING/GASFIT/ssp/ssplist.d` which doesn't exist. Now there are several files that *start* with `ssplist.d`, but none where this is the full name.

If you try to assign an overlong string to a fixed length char variable, the last characters are dropped:

```
program string1
    implicit none
    character(len=8) :: h
    h = "Hello World"
    print *, h
end program string1
```

Prints:

```
Hello Wo
```

My suggestion is to search for the declaration of your character variable `splist`, I suspect it to look something like this:

```
character(len=xx) :: splist
```

but might also be older:

```
character*xx splist
```

or something like this, where `xx` is a number. This `xx` needs to be at least the number of characters in `/Users/.../SSPFITTING/GASFIT/ssp/ssplist.dat08` (I also suspect that you have replaced a long list of subdirectories with `...` so I can't tell you how many characters that are.) My suspicion is that that number is just a little to short.

Comment: I'm going to accept this as a best guess answer given my rather vague question. I realised from this answer that the character length of the splist was indeed ok, set to len=64...it was that my string exceeded this! A little shortening of the directory to this file was sufficient to solve this issue.

Answer (score -1):

Are the slashes are leaning the right way?
You can INQUIRE...

```
LOGICAL :: Existent = .FALSE.
...
INQUIRE(FILE='somefile', EXIST=Existent)
IF(Existent) THEN
  OPEN(...
  READ(...
  CLOSE(...
ELSE
  WRITE(*,10) SomeFile(1:??)
10 FORMAT(" Cannot find file="',A,'"')
ENDIF
```

The main thing that the write statement shows is what is being failed to exist.
If the character string that holds the filename is limitied to 80 characters and you are truncating off the 'at1' then that could give you insight.

Which is long winded way of saying what chw21 said.

Comment: But he wil get FALSE and still has the same problem... If this was the answer we could have closed it as a duplicate, this was here couple of times already.